# Share singleton NSController among multiple nib files

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

How to share a singleton `NSController` among multiple nib files? Like the "Shared User Defaults Controller" provided by Xcode?

Comment: absolutely... provided your singleton class is properly implemented. just add it to each nib.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly implemented"? It appears my nib files skip my `sharedXyzController()` method and each nib file calls `init` once. FYI, I dragged an `NSObject` to each nib file and set its class to `MyXyzController`.

Comment: what i mean is that a "properly implemented" singleton wont actually let you allocate more than one instance. and that `init` and similar methods (copy etc) return the shared instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use for this situation:

```
@implementation MySingletonClass

static MySingletonClass*    instance    = 0;

- (id) init {

    if ( instance )
        return instance;

    return ( instance = self = [super init] );
}

+ (MySingletonClass*) shared {

    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        instance = [[MySingletonClass alloc] init];
    });

    return instance;
}

@end
```